# Sampling from partitions of graph vertices into connected subsets

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, sampling, set-partition

Suppose I have a connected graph $G=(V,E)$, where $E\subseteq V\times V$ contains undirected edges.  For $V'\subseteq V$, denote $G_{V'}$ as the induced subgraph $G_{V'}:=(V',E\cap(V'\times V')).$

Denote $S$ as the set of partitions into two connected components:
$$
S:=\{V'\subseteq V : G_{V'}\textrm{ and }G_{V\backslash V'}\textrm{ are connected subgraphs}\}.
$$
**Is it tractable to sample from $S$ *with uniform probability* for each element?**

---

Apologies for clunky notation.  Some ideas that sample non-uniformly include:

- Randomly draw a spanning tree and cut one edge
- Merge pairs of vertices together until two clusters are left

Comment: This paper recommends a type of reservoir sampling they call Neighbor Reservoir Sampling, but it also assumes you know the partition size $k$ ahead of time, which is probably nonuniform and graph-dependent. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-31235-9_13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.5 years later, I can confidently return to this StackExchange post and answer:  **No, it is not tractable.**

In fact, this question led to [a research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.08881.pdf) with our intern Lorenzo, who appears in the comments of this question.

As outlined in that paper, uniformly sampling graph partitions is dual to uniformly sampling simple cycles in a graph, which even on planar and bounded-degree domains is intractable thanks to a classical result by Jerrum, Valiant, and Vazirani.  The basic construction to prove intractability is to replace each edge in $E$ with a subdivision "gadget" that looks like the following:

[image: Edge subdivision]

Each simple cycle in the subdivided graph either is a two-edge cycle $v\to w\to v$ (the loops shown above) or it corresponds to a simple cycle in the original graph.  The number of times a cycle in the original graph is "lifted" to a cycle in the subdivided graph is proportional to its length.  Hamiltonian cycles get copied the most times --- by an exponential factor!

Hence, uniformly sampling cycles in the subdivided graph gives a randomized algorithm for computing Hamiltonian cycles in the original graph that works with high probability.

The research paper details extensions of this proof for planar, bounded-degree graphs, for which the problem remains intractable.  It also contains some qualitative descriptions of the space of graph partitions inspired by literature in statistical physics.

Answer (score 2):

Some form of rejection sampling would probably work reasonably well. We need to be able to compute two things:

1. The probability, $p(V',\overline{V'})$, that a given partition is obtained.
2. A lower bound, $p*$, for the probability that any partition is obtained.

Then we just generate a partition $(V',\overline{V'})$, accept it with probability $\frac{p^*}{p(V',\overline{V'})}$, and otherwise start over.

In the case of the spanning tree method, let $\tau(H)$ denote the number of spanning trees of a graph $H$. Then 
$$
 p(V', \overline{V'}) \ge \frac{\tau(G[V']) \cdot \tau(G[\overline{V'}]) \cdot |E(V',\overline{V'})|}{\tau(G) \cdot (|V(G)|-1)}.
$$
One possible choice of $p^*$ is to just set the numerator to $1$. By finding a better lower bound, we improve the efficiency of the algorithm, reducing the probability that we start over.

Comment: Haha, amazingly exactly this calculation is on my white board right now!! :-) We were planning to try this tomorrow --- my hope is that the bound for rejection sampling isn't too bad as the graph scales up in size.  So glad to hear our approach is reasonable and independently verified!

Comment: I wonder if there are any easy assumptions we can put on the graph that bound the p value here

Comment: I think that probability is an equality. Namely, $p(V', \bar{V'}) = t(G[V']) (G[\bar{V'}]) E / t(G) ( V(G) - 1)...